# Add objects to package namespace

Tags: r, r-package

I'd like to push a function inside a package namespace so it can access internal objects of that package (let's use stats package as an example). I've tried using

```
myfun <- function(x) print(x)
env = loadNamespace("stats")
assign("myfun", myfun , env)
```

But it is locked. So I've tried to unlock my object

```
unlockBinding("myfun", env)
```

Since myfun doesn't exist yet, I can't unlock it.

Any help ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Along the line of @Hadley's solution, but using the environment of the namespace, how about:

```
environment(myfun) <- asNamespace('stats')
```

Comment: in case that you need to modify an existing package function, which is to be called by other package functions, [here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58238931/684229)

Comment: How do you check whether this has worked successfully?

Answer (score 23):

Why not just set the environment of your new function to the right place?

```
myfun <- function(x) print(x)
environment(myfun) <- as.environment("package:stats")
```

Comment: I didn't know that ! But I think I would like it to be namespace:stats instead of package:stats. Is there way to do that (just changing it in as.environment() doesn't work).

Comment: I'm late to the party, but this may be useful for others: The namespace actually is an environment. `namespace:stats` is a _descendent_ the global environment and contains all the objects. The exported objects get copied over to `package:stats`, which is an _ancestor_ of the global environment.

Answer (score 7):

You can access internal objects of a package using the triple colon operator `:::`.  Take a look at, for example, `as.roman` and `utils:::.roman2numeric`.  (Compare this to `utils::.roman2numeric`.)  This could help you avoid having to put your function inside the namespace.

You might also want to look at `dont.lockBindings` in the `mvbutils` package, which stops namespaces being locked.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I cannot unlock a package's Namespace once it is locked (except by reloading it with dont.lockBindings). So it's impossible to add a new function a posteriori.

Comment: @Etiennebr: AFAIK you are correct.  Once the namespace is locked, you can't add to it.  I still think that `:::` is the way to proceed.