# Ambiguous variation of default environment in `getClasses()` (standard function vs. formal S4 method)

Tags: r, class, default-value, r-s4, lexical-scope

I'm having some trouble figuring out what's exactly going on here with respect to "environment nesting"/lexical scoping:

### The problem

The default value of argument `where` in function `getClasses()` seems to vary depending on whether `getClasses()` is called inside a **standard R function** or a **formal S4 method**. It is controlled by `.externalCallerEnv()` which seems to be "object" to *lazy evaluation* and thus causes the variation (see **EDIT** below)

### The question

When called from inside a formal S4 method, how do I set `where` to the same value that is the default value when `getClasses()` is called inside a standard function?

---

### ILLUSTRATION

Below you'll find a short illustration of the "problematic behavior" described above

### 1) Custom classes

I've got numerous class defs that are currently sourced to `.GlobalEnv`.

Let's take this one as a representative for all of them

```
setRefClass("A", fields=list(x="numeric"))
```

### 2) Listing available classes

Via argument `where`, function `getClasses` lets me choose the environment in which to look for classes.

The following seems to look everywhere except `.GlobalEnv` and thus doesn't find my class; that's fine:

```
classes <- getClasses()
> head(classes)
[1] "("            ".environment" ".externalptr" ".name"        ".NULL"       
[6] ".Other"   
> "A" %in% classes
[1] FALSE
```

Now I look in `.GlobalEnv` and find class `A` only; that's fine too:

```
classes <- getClasses(where=.GlobalEnv)
> classes
[1] "A"
> "A" %in% classes
[1] TRUE
```

### 3) Creating a custom standard lookup function

When I put the lookup via `getClasses` into a **standard function** (this is just the first part of a desired functionality and I'd like to compute `getClasses()` inside that method rather than passing it's return value as an formal argument), everything still works fine

```
foo1 <- function(where=.GlobalEnv) {
    if (is.null(where)) {
        x <- getClasses()
    } else {
        x <- getClasses(where=where)    
    }
    return(x)
}
> foo1()
[1] "A"
> classes <- foo1(where=NULL)
> head(classes)
[1] "("            ".environment" ".externalptr" ".name"        ".NULL"       
[6] ".Other"    
> "A" %in% classes
[1] FALSE
```

### 4) Creating a formal S4 method

However, once I put everything into a **formal S4 method**, there seems to be some changes with respect to the standard environment that `getClasses()` uses to look for classes

```
setGeneric(
    name="foo2",
    signature="x",
    def=function(x, ...) standardGeneric("foo2")       
)
setMethod(
    f="foo2", 
    signature=signature(x="missing"), 
    definition=function(
        x,
        where=.GlobalEnv
    ) {       
    if (is.null(where)) {
        x <- getClasses()
    } else {
        x <- getClasses(where=where)    
    }
    return(x)        
    }
)
[1] "foo2"
> foo2()
[1] "A"
> classes <- foo2(where=NULL)
> head(classes)
[1] "A"            "("            ".environment" ".externalptr" ".name"       
[6] ".NULL"  
> "A" %in% classes
[1] TRUE
```

Before, `"A" %in% foo1(where=NULL)` was `FALSE` (**desired**) whereas `"A" %in% foo2(where=NULL)` is `TRUE` now (**not desired**).

Any ideas how `foo2()` would behave the exact same way as `foo1()`?

---

### EDIT 2012-08-29

As Josh O'Brien pointed out in his comment below, the variation is probably caused by *lazy evaluation*.

### Debugging `foo1()`

```
debug(getClasses)
foo1(where=NULL)
```

You enter the debugging tracer; hit `<RETURN>` **4 times** followed by typing `get("where")`:

```
Browse[2]> get("where")
<environment: namespace:base>
```

In the console, hit `<RETURN>` **1 time** followed by typing `evList`:

```
Browse[2]> evList
[[1]]
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Type `Q` to quit the current debugging run

**Now run everything again, but with slightly different debugging calls**

```
foo1(where=NULL)
```

In the console, hit `<RETURN>` **5 times** followed by typing `evList`:

```
Browse[2]> evList
[[1]]
<environment: namespace:methods>
```

Now type `get("where")`:

```
Browse[2]> get("where")
<environment: namespace:methods>
```

Now `where` points to `namespace:methods`

### Debugging `foo2()'

```
foo2(where=NULL)
```

You enter the debugging tracer; hit `<RETURN>` **4 times** followed by typing `get("where")`:

```
Browse[2]> get("where")
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Then hit `<RETURN>` **1 time** followed by typing `evList`:

```
Browse[2]> evList
[[1]]
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Type `Q` to quit the current debugging run

**Now run everything again, but with slightly different debugging calls**

```
foo2(where=NULL)
```

Hit `<RETURN>` **5 times** followed by typing `evList`:

```
Browse[2]> evList
[[1]]
<environment: 0x02a68db8>

[[2]]
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

# [OMITTED]

[[8]]
<environment: package:methods>
attr(,"name")
[1] "package:methods"
attr(,"path")
[1] "R:/Apps/LSQMApps/apps/R/R-2.14.1/library/methods"

[[9]]
<environment: 0x01e8501c>
attr(,"name")
[1] "Autoloads"

[[10]]
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Now type `get("where")`:

```
Browse[2]> get("where")
<environment: 0x02a68db8>
```

and note the different values of `evList` and `where` compared to the debugging run before. Type `Q` to quit the current debugging run.

**This seems somewhat strange to me, but probably makes sense from the language designers' perspective. I'd probably be fine once I know how to explicitly set `where` to point to the environment associated with the `namespace:methods`.**

Comment: +1 Very interesting. I'm guessing it's got to do with lazy evaluation of `getClasses()`' `where = .externalCallerEnv()` argument, as the following seems to indicate. Try  `debug(getClasses);foo2(where=NULL)` followed by `<RET>; <RET>; <RET>; get("where"); <RET>; evList; get("where")`, vs. `foo2(where=NULL)` followed by `<RET>; <RET>; <RET>; <RET>; evList; get("where")`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: cool, thanks a lot! I definitely have to get more used to using the available debugging functionality ;-) I included your comments as an edit in the original post. This behavior seems somewhat strange to me, but probably makes sense from the language designer's perspective. I think I found a solution (see answer below) but this "variable default behavior" due to lazy evaluation still bothers me a little - but that might just be me. Do you think it's worth letting the guys at r-devel know, or does this all make perfect sense?

Comment: I wouldn't report this, as it looks like `getClasses()` is performing just as it was intended to (see `where=` in the `?getClasses`). My guess is that `getClasses()` simply wasn't designed for use inside of an S3 function: it's `foo1`'s behavior that's wonky, and you shouldn't expect `foo2`'s behavior to follow it. `foo1(where=NULL)` and `foo2(where=NULL)` give different results because `environment(foo1)` and `environment(foo2)` are different (even though `ls()` shows they're both located in the global environment). So lazy evaluation, though it occurs, is a red herring here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A well known lesson learned yet again: it's always good to be explicit ;-)**

Thanks to [Josh O'Brien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980833/josh-obrien) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094232/add-objects-to-package-namespace) by [Etiennebr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171659/etiennebr) I guess I'm able to put the pieces together.

Due to *lazy evaluation* and *lexical scoping*, I think the only way to really **make sure** `getClasses()` behaves the same way as if called from either `.GlobalEnv` or from inside a regular function is to explicitly set the value of `where` to the environment associated to `namespace:methods` when calling `getClasses()` inside a formal S4 method.

To get the environment associated to the namespace, this seems to work:

```
env <- loadNamespace("methods")
> is.environment(env)
[1] TRUE
```

Alternatively or even better:

```
env <- asNamespace("methods")
> is.environment(env)
[1] TRUE
```

This environment is exactly the one we need to point `where` to

```
setGeneric(
    name="foo2",
    signature="x",
    def=function(x, ...) standardGeneric("foo2")       
)
setMethod(
    f="foo2", 
    signature=signature(x="missing"), 
    definition=function(
        x,
        where=.GlobalEnv
    ) {       
    if (is.null(where)) {
        x <- getClasses(where=asNamespace("methods"))
    } else {
        x <- getClasses(where=where)
    }
    return(x)       
    }
)

> foo2()
[1] "A"
> classes <- foo2(where=NULL)
> head(classes)
[1] "("            ".environment" ".externalptr" ".name"        ".NULL"       
[6] ".Other"      
> "A" %in% classes
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: A minor note: I'd prob. use `asNamespace("methods")` instead of `loadNamespace("methods")` since the namespace is already loaded and you are just wanting a pointer to it.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: great, thanks. That seemed superfluous to me as well, but I didn't know how to do it differently.