# How to add a class to a loaded package in R

Tags: r, class, package, extend

I am working on extending a class in a pre-existing package (xcms) in R.  What I would like to do is include my class in the package after loading the package since there are non-exported methods in the package my extended class will need to use.  Example below.

Package xcms

Class to extend foo

Extended class foo2

Now I want to be able to do the following:

library(xcms)

setClass(foo2,....)

'define functions of foo2'

'insert foo2 into xcms somehow so it can see all of the non-exported functions and classes'

Cole

Comment: Here's a question from a few years ago with several good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094232/add-objects-to-package-namespace

Comment: Awesome! I tried searching for something like that but couldn't find anything for the life of me.  How did you find that?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't show up under the Related sidebar either. I got there by Googling "r package environment". I was curious myself.

Comment: You should post the link as an answer.