# How to use ggplot_add inside another package

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-s3

I'm trying to build a package for data visualisation that relies heavily on ggplot2, but has some custom shortcuts for some of the day to day problems I face.

I am able to use `ggplot_add` function to extend the functionality of `+` for custom classes from scripts, however when I add these scripts to a package, `ggplot_add` no longer works.

Below I paste a minrep, to replicate first one needs to create a package (I'm using RStudio), that I've called SOExa.
That project contains the following files:

**.Rbuildignore**

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
```

**DESCRIPTION**

```
Package: SOExa
Type: Package
Title: An minrep for a problem I'm having
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Col Bates
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: I want to use ggplot2's ggplot_add from inside another package, i.e. this one.
    It seems that when I do I get an error.
License: GPLv2
Encoding: UTF-8
Imports:
    dplyr,
    magrittr,
    tidyr,
    glue,
    ggplot2
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
```

My project file `SOExa.Rproj`

A folder called R, containing the minrep example of use:

**R/designed_by.R**

```
#' the function to add a 'designed by' to the plot
#' as a designed_by class
#'@export
designed_by<-function(x){
  return(new_designed_by(x))
}


#' generic constructor.
#' @export
new_designed_by<-function(x){
  x <- list('designed_by' = x)
  class(x) <- 'designed_by'
  return(x)
}


#' generic print for designed_by
#' @export
print.designed_by <- function(x){
  print(paste('Designed by:', format(x)))

}


#' defines the addition of an designed_by object for
#' @export
ggplot_add.designed_by <- function(object, plot, objectname){
  plot$designed_by <-  object$designed_by
  plot
}

ggplot_add <- function(x){
  UseMethod("ggplot_add")
  }
```

I run the following code to build the Namespace file

```
devtools::document()
```

A new file is created:

**NAMESPACE**

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

S3method(ggplot_add,designed_by)
S3method(print,designed_by)
export(designed_by)
export(new_designed_by)
```

After this I install and load the library:

```
devtools::install()
library(SOExa)
```

Then creating an empty plot:

```
p <- ggplot2::ggplot()
```

The following will give rise to an error:

```
p <- p + designed_by('Col Bates')
```

The error I get is:

```
# Error: Can't add `designed_by("Col Bates")` to a ggplot object.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

So following those steps:

```
rlang::last_error()
```

Which returns

```
# <error/rlang_error>
#   Can't add `designed_by("Col Bates")` to a ggplot object.
# Backtrace:
#  1. ggplot2:::`+.gg`(p, designed_by("Col Bates"))
#  2. ggplot2:::add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
#  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_add.default(object, p, objectname)
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Running

```
rlang::last_trace()
```

I get

```
<error/rlang_error>
Can't add `designed_by("Col Bates")` to a ggplot object.
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-ggplot2:::`+.gg`(p, designed_by("Col Bates"))
 2.   \-ggplot2:::add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
 3.     +-ggplot2::ggplot_add(object, p, objectname)
 4.     \-ggplot2:::ggplot_add.default(object, p, objectname)
```

From this I can deduce that ggplot2::ggplot_add(), which calls `UseMethod('ggplot_add')` has invoked decided to apply the function `ggplot_add.default`, and hasn't recognised my class `designed_by`.

Incidentally, using the `print()` function does work from the library.

```
print(designed_by('Col Bates'))
```

However, if I were to source the script, rather than use the package like the following:

```
source('./R/designed_by.R')
p <- p + designed_by('Col Bates')
```

It does indeed work the way I would expect.

Looking deeper into things,  I can see that  the source of the generic `ggplot_add` on the class `designed_by` is my package.

```
 sloop::s3_methods_generic("ggplot_add")
## A tibble: 1 x 4
#  generic    class       visible source
#  <chr>      <chr>       <lgl>   <chr> 
# 1 ggplot_add designed_by TRUE    SOExa
```

Whereas with ggplot classes it is 'registered S3method'

```
> sloop::s3_methods_generic("ggplot_add")
## A tibble: 14 x 4
#   generic    class      visible source             
#   <chr>      <chr>      <lgl>   <chr>              
# 1 ggplot_add by         FALSE   registered S3method
# 2 ggplot_add Coord      FALSE   registered S3method
# 3 ggplot_add data.frame FALSE   registered S3method
# 4 ggplot_add default    FALSE   registered S3method
# 5 ggplot_add Facet      FALSE   registered S3method
# ...
```

I looked inside the [ggplot2](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2) source code, but couldn't really figure out how this works. I've also been reading https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html but haven't seen anything about using S3methods which apply to classes from another library.

It would be great to figure out if it is possible to package the calls into my custom package, or if I would always need to rely on sourcing.

Thanks.

Comment: I THINK you'll need to assign your method `ggplot_add.designed_by` to the ggplot2 namespace.  [Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094232/add-objects-to-package-namespace)

Comment: Thanks for this @SmokeyShakers, but I think this solution still only works from the command line. At least as I've tried to implement it it only worked this way. This is still useful however, as it points at the namespace as being a direction I should look to.

Comment: Where did you try it? You may need it in your package's `onLoad`

Comment: I tried both in the onLoad as well as within the file where `ggplot_add.designed_by` was defined.

Comment: I think the problem is your `ggplot_add` function. If you remove that, all seems to work when you declare `ggplot2` in your DESCRIPTION file, either under `Depends` or `Imports`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup should work if you add `ggplot2` to `Depends` rather than `Imports` in the `DESCRIPTION` file. For example, if I create a new package with the following files:

**.Rbuildignore**

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
```

**DESCRIPTION**

```
Package: SOExa
Type: Package
Title: An minrep for a problem I'm having
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Col Bates
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: I want to use ggplot2's ggplot_add from inside another package, i.e. this one.
    It seems that when I do I get an error.
License: GPLv2
Encoding: UTF-8
Depends: ggplot2
Imports:
    dplyr,
    magrittr,
    tidyr,
    glue
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
```

**designed_by.R**

```r
#' the function to add a 'designed by' to the plot
#' as a designed_by class
#'@export
designed_by<-function(x){
  return(new_designed_by(x))
}


#' generic constructor.
#' @export
new_designed_by<-function(x){
  x <- list('designed_by' = x)
  class(x) <- 'designed_by'
  return(x)
}


#' generic print for designed_by
#' @export
print.designed_by <- function(x){
  print(paste('Designed by:', format(x)))

}


#' defines the addition of an designed_by object for
#' @export
ggplot_add.designed_by <- function(object, plot, objectname){
  plot$designed_by <-  object$designed_by
  plot
}
```

Then running `devtools::document()` gives me:

**NAMESPACE**

```r
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

S3method(ggplot_add,designed_by)
S3method(print,designed_by)
export(designed_by)
export(new_designed_by)
```

So after I do `devtools::install()` I get the following output:

```r
library(SOExa)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

p <- ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)) + geom_point()

p <- p + designed_by('Col Bates')

p
```

[image]

```r
p$designed_by
#> [1] "Col Bates"
```

Comment: Thank you Allan! This indeed did the trick! I'm really pleased.

Comment: In case future users happen upon this post, I really want to point out that putting `ggplot2` in depends vs imports really is NOT the issue. The only difference between depends and imports is that packages in depends will be loaded when your package is loaded. Since its loaded you no longer need to declare `#' @import {package}` for `roxygen2`. The issue is how to export an S3 method for a generic in another package. A good example is the `vctrs` as they have documentation on how to [extend their generics if you were making a package](https://vctrs.r-lib.org/articles/s3-vector.html)

Comment: @JustinLandis yes, what you say about exporting an S3 method for a generic in another package is correct, but given the stated use case of this package effectively being a wrapper / extender for `ggplot2`, then the easiest and most natural way to achieve this is by moving `ggplot2` to `Depends`. If you can make a reproducible example that works as well, please add this as an answer. I would happily upvote it. Your existing answer unfortunately results in the same error that the OP describes.

Comment: @Allan Cameron, see my last comment on my answer. The OP's error is a result of having defined `ggplot_add <- function(x) UseMethod("ggplot_add")` within their package, as seen in their post. If you included this in your reprex package - even with `ggplot2` in depends, you will also get the error.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common issue that trips me up a lot. You will need to make sure your package has access to `ggplot2`'s `ggplot_add` generic function. You do this one of two ways.

You will need to include the following line somewhere in your package:

```
#' @import ggplot2
```

which will make all ggplot2 functions available, or if you will only be making use of that function do:

```
#' @importFrom ggplot2 ggplot_add
```

It's a bit unintuitive, but just because the `DESCRIPTION` file says that it imports a package, does not mean your package's namespace will be able to see that package's functions. You can always check this by viewing the `NAMESPACE` file. When you include the suggestion above you should see one of the following lines at the bottom of the `NAMESPACE` file

```
import(ggplot2)
importFrom(ggplot2,ggplot_add)
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, I've tried this out, I created a file imports.R and added two lines, the first `#' @import ggplot2` followed by a line which reads `NULL`. The NAMESPACE updates the way you describe, but the function is still not accessible and the above code generates the same errors.

Comment: I've tested it a few more times, make sure you don't have your own definition of `ggplot_add` defined in your package. It seems to cause the error. My guess is that your package will register `ggplot_add.designed_by` to your internal, non-exported `ggplot_add`.