# Setting the environment of a function to the package environment it came from

Tags: r, function, package

I have a function that is part of my own package. When called from `namespace:package_name`, the function behaves slightly different than when it is called from `R_GlobalEnv`. To find out why I want to debug the function.

To make debugging the function as easy as possible, I want to write the changes I made to the function to the `namespace:package_name` environment, so I can immediately test it, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

If I type `namespace:package_name`, it gives the environment at the bottom as follows:

```
<bytecode: 0x00000236403c9da0>
<environment: namespace:package_name>
```

But if I try `environment(fun) <- namespace:package_name`, it says:

```
Error: object 'namespace' not found.
```

How do I set the environment of my function to the package environment?

## EDIT:

Surprisingly `fixInNamespace` does not leave the `namespace` intact.

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right but, can't you reinstall it (a git branch perhaps) with the changes applied?

Comment: @Paladinic Of course, but this is what I am trying to circumvent..

Comment: `pacman:p_temp` might work, I haven't tried it for a package I've already got installed though - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pacman/versions/0.5.1/topics/p_temp. It works by installing the package in to a temporary directory that's then removed after the session is over

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add objects to package namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094232/add-objects-to-package-namespace)